# Why did Drogon allow this character to pet him?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Why did Drogon allow Jon Snow to pet him in *Game of Thrones* S07E06? What could be the possible reasons for that when the dragons only listen to Daenerys Targaryen.

Comment: Probably something like: He respects him or because he is a Targaryen.

Comment: Changed the title to be spoilerfree.

Answer (score 5):

As elaborated in [this article](http://heavy.com/entertainment/2017/08/why-does-did-drogon-like-jon-snow-game-of-thrones-theories-explanation/):

> The best idea for why Dragon seems to like Jon Snow is because of Jon’s Targaryen blood. As we learned last season, Jon is *not* Ned Stark’s bastard child, but is actually the child of Prince Rhaegar (Dany’s older brother) and Lyanna Stark, Ned’s sister.
>
> The Targaryen in Jon Snow’s blood is likely making Drogon more amiable to him. Daenerys thinks she’s the last Targaryen left, which makes Drogon's reaction to Jon even *more* surprising.
>
> Book readers know that not every one of Targaryen blood is automatically friends with all dragons. But it’s unclear if that’s the case in the show.

Comment: I wonder if the phrase "If I pet her dragon and it does not eat me, it will make her hot for me" was in his thought bubble at the time.

Comment: It should also be noted that Targaryen blood is not necessary to get close to dragons as Tyrion is able to approach and unchain them in S6E2.

Comment: @Virusbomb There is also a theory that Tyrion has Targaryen blood: https://winteriscoming.net/2016/05/06/game-of-thrones-theorycrafting-is-tyrion-lannister-actually-a-targaryen/

Comment: As a book reader, I think we should point out while every Valyrian doesn't automatically become friend with _someone else's_ dragon, they can do so with unclaimed dragons. And Dragons let people who they are familiar with come near them and touch them, regardless to their blood status. And the Dragons know  friends, enemies and families of their riders due to their strong magical bond, so they know who should they hurt and who should they let be.

Comment: @Aegon Also, according to GRRM, Jon Snow has no blood pumping through his veins anymore - he is a (fire) wight, so the presence of Targaryen blood oughtn't to be a factor here, unless this is another one of those show-divergences.

Comment: @Aegon Also, I heard that there is a term (in the books) for people who aren't Targaryen's but have a particular affinity for dragons that is special, and allows them to more easily approach dragons and even form bonds with them - something like (but not) dragonkin. Any ideas?

Comment: Fire wight was more of a metaphor I believe, not literal. And yes that's those with a drop of dragon blood in them e.g. brown ben plumm, who was loved by dany's dragons. They can't bond tho, as quentyn martell found out. The ones who can bond are dragonseeds, bastards of valyrians.

Comment: @Aegon Personally, I would find an answer that details all the different ways a person can achieve a moment like the one we see in the show (dragonseeds, Targaryen, part-Targaryen, being familiar with the person through their rider/bonded Targaryen) and breaks down the likelihood of how each scenario applies to Jon Snow much more compelling than the answer we're commenting on at the minute.

Comment: @Aegon Having just rewatched the Hound and Beric's scene, he definitely has blood running through his veins (screenshot [here](https://image.prntscr.com/image/FWSsXIM4SniuJS_E5ss7kQ.png)), at least in the show - so perhaps it *is* as simple as being a Targaryen/dragonseed, with Jon (in the show).